# If a complex function is holomorphic in the upper half complex plane and $Im f'(z) >0$ prove that f is one to one

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $f$ is a complex function which is holomorphic on the upper half complex plane and $Im (f'(z)) >0$. I  need to prove that f is on to one but I seem to have found a couterexample so I don't know what I a m doing wrong.

If $z=x+iy$ define $f(z)= x +8 + i(2x-y^2)$. Then if $f'(z)= 1/2(df/dx-idf/dy)$ we have $f'(z)= 1/2(1+2i-i(-2iy))=1/2(1+2i-2y)=i+1/2-y$ so $Imf'(z)=1>0$ but f is not one to one since $f(3i)=8-9i=f(-3i)$.

where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you want one to one on the upper half plane or the entire plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is not holomorphic. It does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Write $f = u+iv$ for $u,v$ real. Then, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$ while $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 2$.

To prove the result, a hint is take any two points $w_1,w_2$ in the upper half plane and look at the path integral over any curve connecting them.